# ASP.NET: Use ID from query against a SQL Server view used in a GridView to control DetailsView that queries a table

Tags: asp.net

Please forgive my ignorance. I have a done a bit of web programming but am new to ASP.NET and find it mystifying when trying to do something not out of the box.

I have a GridView that gets its data from a SQL Server view. I have a DetailsView that needs to manipulate data in a table. I cannot figure out how to link the GridView to the DetailsView correctly.

Below is the code for the section of the aspx page that contains the GridView and DetailsView. The latest error in an endless procession of errors is: Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".

I would appreciate any help that anyone can offer. Thanks.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvVendorContacts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="dsApplications_Contacts" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4"   CellSpacing="2" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" DataKeyNames="ContactID"
    onselectedindexchanged="gvVendorContacts_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E8F3FF" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="FullName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Role" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="Role" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Office Phone" HeaderText="Office Phone" 
            SortExpression="Office Phone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile Phone" HeaderText="Mobile Phone" 
            SortExpression="Mobile Phone" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="Mailto:<%# Eval("Email") %>"><%#Eval("Email")%></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsApplications_Contacts" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MDSConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ApplicationID], [ContactID], [FName], [LName], [FullName], [Title], [Role], [OfficePhone] As [Office Phone], [MobilePhone] As [Mobile Phone], [Email] FROM [vw_Applications_Contacts] WHERE ApplicationName = 'Bloomberg'">
</asp:SqlDataSource>




 <asp:DetailsView ID="dvVendorContacts" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
     DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="dsVendorContacts" Height="100px" 
     Width="200px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" 
     BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4">
     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
     <Fields>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
             ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="FName" HeaderText="FName" SortExpression="FName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="LName" HeaderText="LName" SortExpression="LName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Role" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="Role" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="OfficePhone" HeaderText="OfficePhone" 
             SortExpression="OfficePhone" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="MobilePhone" HeaderText="MobilePhone" 
             SortExpression="MobilePhone" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
     </Fields>
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
 </asp:DetailsView>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsVendorContacts" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MDSConnectionString %>" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Contacts] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Contacts] ([FName], [LName], [Title], [Role], [OfficePhone], [MobilePhone], [Email]) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @Title, @Role, @OfficePhone, @MobilePhone, @Email)" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [FName], [LName], [Title], [Role], [OfficePhone], [MobilePhone], [Email] FROM [Contacts] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)" 
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Contacts] SET [FName] = @FName, [LName] = @LName, [Title] = @Title, [Role] = @Role, [OfficePhone] = @OfficePhone, [MobilePhone] = @MobilePhone, [Email] = @Email WHERE [ID] = @ID">
     <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>
     <InsertParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="FName" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="LName" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Role" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="OfficePhone" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="MobilePhone" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
     </InsertParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="FName" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="LName" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Role" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="OfficePhone" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="MobilePhone" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
     </UpdateParameters>
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvVendorContacts" DefaultValue="NULL" 
        Name="ContactID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your select statement is expecting @ID but your SelectParameter is ContactId.